# How do I create a reocurring calendar entry that ends at some time?

Tags: calendar

I am taking a class at the same time on several date throughout the month. Is it possible to copy the calendar event from one week to the next without retyping the event each time. I will be attending the class a total of thirteen times.

Answer (score 1):

I've never found a way to copy and paste a calendar event - something for the wish list!
But... you can use the repeat function within the event to repeat it to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities:

- Go to [Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/render?tab=mc&pli=1) and add your event (reocurring and ending at a specific date)
- Using the app: Add a reocurring (never ending) event, then go to the first date you don't want the event to occur any more and delete it with option **This and future events**